# Bash script to use .bash_profiles

Tags: macos, bash

I keep getting "not found" errors when I use commands inside of my bash script.

If I use the terminal normally, the commands work.

I suspect it is not using the .bash_profiles so it can't find the paths?

Here is my bash script

```
# ~/.bash_profile
bash --login
open Applications/Postgres.app/

cd Users/mac1/Dev/TEST
sublime App23
. 2vennv/bin/activate
cd App23/
./manage.py runserver
bash
```

Comment: What is this *script*? Is it your bash profile or something you try to run from the Terminal. What is `cd ..; cd ..;` supposed to do? Why have you executed `wait` when you seem to have no background processes to wait for? What are you actually trying to do - just in English?

Comment: I've adjusted it. I've removed the wait. It is a simple script to navigate to a directory, open an app, open a folder in sublime, then run a file (python). Can you please assist?

Comment: Personally, I would remove both lines that start with `bash` and add a new first line that says `#!/bin/bash -xv` and try re-running it so you can debug what it is doing. You may also need to add `&` to the end of any lines if it hangs at any point so that the line with `&` at the end get executed in the background and your script can continue.

Comment: Scripts should generally not need to `cd` around a lot.  You are using relative paths throughout, which means this script will only work if you start it in a directory where these subdirectories exist.  I'm guessing you mean for these paths to be relative to the root directory; but just say so (i.e. `/Applications/` instead of `Applications/`, `/Users/` instead of `Users/`, etc) and take out any interactive programs (or run them in the background).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on DIRS. When running commands in bash, I get "command not found" because (I assume) it's not find paths in .bash_profiles . Can you advise on that?

Comment: Which commands do you get "command not found" on?    Did you use run trace (`-xv`) as @MarkSetchell suggested?

Comment: I used `-xv` but it doesn't give me any more information. It just says "sublime: command not found". Sublime is the command that doesnt work. The command works fine if I used it manually elsewhere

Comment: OK, so it can't find `sublime`.  Which directory is `sublime` in, and is it in the list of directories in `$PATH`?

Comment: `alias sublime="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app"
export` and `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Aliases are not expanded in scripts by default.   Either put the alias in your script or use `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Comment: sublime: command not found is still happening. Please tell me the alias I would use?

Comment: Read the instruction again. Don't use an alias. Maybe define it as a function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason the command `sublime` doesn't work inside of Bashscripts/sh files.

I used `subl` instead and it worked

```
# ~/.bash_profile
bash --login
open Applications/Postgres.app/

cd Users/mac1/Dev/TEST
sub App23
. 2vennv/bin/activate
cd App23/
./manage.py runserver
bash
```